# Viewport ignoring custom width

Tags: html, viewport

I am playing around with viewport and tried to do a width of 520, but it seems to do device-width instead. Any ideas?

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=520, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<style type="text/css">
h1
{
    width: 980px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

h2
{
    width: 520px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

h3
{
    width: 320px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<h1>I am a big heading 980px wide. Yes I am</h1>
<h2>I am a big heading 520px wide. Yes I am</h2>
<h3>I am a big heading 320 wide. Yes I am</h3>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you read [this great article](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports2.html) explaining what do pixels mean for the mobile viewports?

Comment: Is there a special reason for you not to set a `DOCTYPE`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For pages that set an initial or maximum scale, this means the width property actually translates into a minimum Viewport width. For example, if your layout needs at least 500 pixels of width then you can use the following markup. When the screen is more than 500 pixels wide, the browser will expand the Viewport (rather than zoom in) to fit the screen:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=500, initial-scale=1">
```

This was derived from this [LINK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag).

So I am assuming that in your case too since you have set the html tags width to more than 520px the browser is taking the 520px width as minumum width and working upwards from there to render the larger tags.

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/viewport-meta-tag-for-non-responsive-design) seems to suggest that `content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"` is the issue, and that if you're trying to create a fixed viewport they should be omitted.

I haven't had a chance to test it myself, but the rationale seems sound.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to rely on the viewport meta tag for width. As [this article](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports2.html) points out:

> Sometimes the formal `screen.width` does not make much sense because the pixel count is just too high. For instance, the Nexus One
>   has a formal width of 480px, but Google engineers have decided that
>   giving the layout viewport a width of 480px when using device-width is
>   just too much. They shrank it to 2/3rds, so that device-width gives
>   you a width of 320px, just as on the iPhone.

Those 320px are "CSS Pixels," meaning that 320 pixels is the width of the viewport, no matter how wide the device or document actually is.

If you are specifying a width larger (or smaller) than the phone's actual size and restricting scale, you will have problems. Try removing `initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,` to allow the browser to scale the page to fit the device correctly. You can still keep `user-scalable=no` and `width=520`.

Answer (score -1):

Your Header tag(H1, H2, H3) width are 980px, 520px and 320px respectively.Your headers tag has hard coded width hence what ever the device width will be but your header tag width will be same and will not become responsive. I think instead of providing width in pixel why you don't use width in %. And you can also put the header tag in one container made that container `position:relative` even you can made relative to your individuals header tag.